# hide column (header and rows) post jqGrid render

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to hide a specific column in jqGrid after it has been setup, while ensuring all alignments are correct (table width and header/data alignment) for IE/FF.

The data can't be removed at back-end w/o major refactoring.

I am reiterating through a specific column and checking if it is all empty, and if so, I tried .remove() on the header and cells for that column, but the alignment goes off seriously (I think setGridWidth is still taking into account that removed column's width). I know there is a hide option when jqGrid initialises... but not sure if there is a method for that post render.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `hideCol` and `showCol` methods for hiding and showing columns after the jqGrid is created. The method `hideCol` doesn't remove any of the data from the jqGrid but only hides the specified column. See http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods for details.

I recommend examining the `loadComplete` event. You can get IDs of the loaded data using the `getDataIDs` method, then get the row data in a loop using `getRowData`. Make sure to check for empty data. Don't forget to call `showCol` for all columns you previously hid. You can always call `showCol` for all columns that should be seen and call `hideCol` for all columns you want to hide.